# How do I get Internal declarations to not be included in the project-swift.h file

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, frameworks

I am trying to create a framework to use inside an Xamarin project. I am using sharpie to create the ApiDefinitions.cs file. However the project name-swift.h file has declarations that are internal which I do not want to be in the ApiDefinitions.cs.
Apple documentation says:

> Because the generated header is part of the framework’s public
> interface, only declarations marked with the public or open modifier
> appear in the generated header for a framework target. Methods and
> properties that are marked with the internal modifier and declared
> within a class that inherits from an Objective-C class are accessible
> to the Objective-C runtime. However, they're inaccessible at compile
> time and don't appear in the generated header for a framework target.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c

In my project the build setting for Objective-C Bridging Header is not set, so I would expect that only open or public should be included.

Example class:

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift

class AddOnsViewController: UIViewController {

    var bag = DisposeBag()
    private var viewModel: AddOnsViewModel!

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    init(viewModel: AddOnsViewModel) {
        super.init(nibName: "\(AddOnsViewController.self)", bundle: nil)
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = NSLocalizedString("Add Ons", comment: " ")

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

#if DEBUG
    deinit {
        print("deinit \(self)")
    }
#endif
}
```

Product-swift.h has:

```
@class NSCoder;
@class NSString;
@class NSBundle;

SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC9Xactimate20AddOnsViewController")
@interface AddOnsViewController : UIViewController
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)coder OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)viewDidLoad;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString * _Nullable)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle * _Nullable)nibBundleOrNil SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
@end
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the problem? I.e. how some class you don't expect to be visible is defined in Swift, and how it appears in `-Swift.h` file?

Comment: added example of the problem

Comment: if the issue is with UIViewController (and other UIKit components), then I think you are out of luck. I didn't see any official confirmation for this, but I believe the reason is because storyboard-based UI is largely Obj-c based, so apple automatically exposes these classes to objc, so you don't need to mark each as @objc. So... "switch to SwiftUI" (that was a joke btw)